# ExtJs - what are the methods to display the description for the field?

Tags: extjs

Which have the means to derive a description of the field (such as text, combobox) of the table in front of the text input field?
Appearance that was:

[image]

ie a question mark next to the field - it points to a question mark - shows information on the field. When the mouse is a query to the database from there from a particular table to get a description of the field.
How best to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/akat/UgLN4/

(You will have to use an appropriate image and probably style it so that it looks 'better')

Answer (score 1):

A pretty ugly but easy way to do this is just to include the HTML for the icon in the description.

```
new Ext.FormPanel({
    height: 100,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Status <img src="./questionmark.png" title="User status" />'
    }]
})
```

It might be more elegant to look at writing a plugin for *Ext.form.Field* .